# Android Tasker : How to disable End Call button while call in progress

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, tasker

I want to create a profile in Tasker in Kitkat Android, to disable the End Call button while I am in the call. I need to do this to stop accidentally touching it or my cheek touching it. I tried couple of apps and they do not exactly serve my purpose.

I welcome your ideas.

Thanks
Sudhi

Comment: And what code have you written so far?

Comment: In the tasker I have created a profile with Call > Any and Wait > Go Home. But instead of Go Home, I need to lock the End Call button. I did not find this option.

Comment: You need to post your code. Can't tell you what is going on with no code to reference.

Comment: I just posted what I did in tasker. I do not see any code/program in tasker.